# Prove a bounded operator and compute norm

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, normed-spaces

Consider an operator $T:L^2[0,1]\to L^2[0,1]$ and $Tf(t)=\int_0^t e^{-(t-x)}f(x)dx$. Prove $T$ is bounded and calculate its norm.

To show it is bounded, we need to calculate $\|Tf\|\leq c\|f\|$ for some constant $c$. I have some problems of finding $c$, and calculating its norm, that is, $\|T\|=\sup_{\|f\|=1}\|Tf\|$.

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: I tried to prove boundedness through Cauchy-Schwarz inequality, $\|Tf\|^2\leq\int_0^1(\int_0^t e^{-(t-x)}dx)(\int_0^t |f(x)|^2dx)dt$$=$$\int_0^1(1-e^{-t})(\int_0^t |f(x)|^2dx)dt$, then I'm stuck.

Comment: Hint: Think of it as a double integral.

Comment: Are you able to appeal to [Young's Inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Young%27s_convolution_inequality)?